# Паттерны Команда и Стратегия (Command and Strategy GOF patterns)

Tags: любой-язык, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-стратегия

В чём принципиальная разница между паттернами команда и стратегия?

Оба поведенческие паттерны. И тот и другой инкапсулируют логику метода отделяя интерфейс от бизнес-логики. Эти паттерны не одно и то же?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что удалось найти на английском stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834979/difference-between-strategy-pattern-and-command-pattern

Если коротко, Стратегия - это изменение алгоритма действия, а Команда - изменение действия.

Comment: стратегия — это обычная лямбда-функция или `enum`, содержащий способ выполнения действия, например, `System.MidpointRounding` для метода `System.Math.Round`. команда — это именно... команда! например, её можно записать в историю команд, или сделать отменяемой. а вообще есть [вот такой хороший сайт](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns).

Comment: "Команда — это поведенческий паттерн проектирования, который превращает запросы в объекты, позволяя передавать их как аргументы при вызове методов, ставить запросы в очередь, логировать их, а также поддерживать отмену операций." мне кажется, тут более точно сказано